# UIAlert Delegates, are they causing conflicts with other part of an app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uialertview

I tried to add an UIAlert to my app and it started to cause a crash.

So i commented out my code and only left this method

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{
}
```

And added the interface

```
<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate >
```

But when an Alert that was already in the app pops, even though its in another class in the app. It crashes as soon as i press ok on the alert.

Is there some kinda of strange conflict with Alerts that I've never come across?

Anybody able to suggest what might be going on. The app crashes without any output to the debug console. So no hint of what the problem maybe.

THanks
-Code

Comment: May be you should try to see the Console output first.

Comment: Hi Jirapong. As i said : The app crashes without any output to the debug console. If the console was giving me a hint I wouldnt be asking for your guys intuition as to what might be going on.

Comment: crashing without a hint is usually an over releasing issue or logging a pointer as an int

Comment: Your problem is probably more to do with the original alert - can you post the code where you create both alerts?

Comment: what do you mean when you say 'Alert that was already in the app pops, even though its in another class in the app'??

Comment: @ lukya. In class-A i added the above code. The class-A finished executing and passed control to class-B. Class-B does it stuff then later pops an Alert. When I dismiss this alert the app crashes. This only happened since the code was added to Class-A. Removing the above code from Class-A and there are no crashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there are no strange conflicts with alerts. You can even have multiple alerts from a single class if you the `tag` property and check for that in the delegate.

Normally a crash indicates that you've released the delegate too early. When you add a delegate it does not retain it (to avoid release cycles) so you have to manually make sure it's still around when the button is pressed.

You can verify this by putting a breakpoint in all your delegate methods.

Answer (score 0):

Base on your answer to comments above. It looks like your delegate object is release early. I'm not sure how you declare the UIAlert, but normally I do like this.

1. Use UIAlertViewDelegate as you did
2. implement clickedButtonAtIndex as you did
3. call UIAlert and release it in one method like this

/* code */

```
-(void) showSomething
{
    UIAlertView *av = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title here"
                        message:@"message here."
                        delegate:self
                        cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                        otherButtonTitles:@"Settings", nil] autorelease];

    [av show];
}
```

Hope this help.